# R: calculate just with times (to find for example a pace per km)

Tags: r

How divide or add times? I have a time in a race of 10 km and I want to find the pace per km for each runner from the result of the race.
For example, if I have a `data.frame` with a column `time` as `00:50:00` in a row (for example) for a run of 10 km how can I find the pace for 1 km ("00:50:00" / 10 km). With `strptime` I transform the string in `H:M:S` but when I will divide the column by 10 to find the pace in one km, R answers `Erreur dans Ops.POSIXt(d$temps, 10) :  '/' non défini pour des objets "POSIXt`. And I have unexpected date in time with `strptime`.
Thanks

Comment: Before doing date/time arithmetic, [you need to convert to date objets](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12649641/calculating-time-difference-in-r).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is one approach.

```
id <- c("ana", "bob", "caroline")
time <- c("00:50:00", "00:37:00", "00:41:30")

foo <- data.frame(id, time, stringsAsFactors=F)

library(chron)
foo$time <- chron(times=foo$time)

        id     time
1      ana 00:50:00
2      bob 00:37:00
3 caroline 00:41:30

foo$pace <- foo$time / 10

        id     time     pace
1      ana 00:50:00 00:05:00
2      bob 00:37:00 00:03:42
3 caroline 00:41:30 00:04:09
```

Answer (score 0):

Since you didn't provide a [reproducible question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example) and we don't know what format your data is in I've mocked up the following:

```
time1 <- as.POSIXct(Sys.time())
time2 <- time1 + 1000 # add 1000 seconds-16 2/3 mins
time_elapsed <- time1-time2
distance <- 10
time_elap_dist <- time_elapsed/distance
# Time difference of -1.666667 mins
```

To do calculations with time you need your data to be in the correct format.