# R difftime subtracts 2 days

Tags: r, difftime

I have some timedelta strings which were exported from Python. I'm trying to import them for use in R, but I'm getting some weird results.

When the timedeltas are small, I get results that are off by 2 days, e.g.:

```
> as.difftime('26 days 04:53:36.000000000',format='%d days %H:%M:%S.000000000')

Time difference of 24.20389 days
```

When they are larger, it doesn't work at all:

```
> as.difftime('36 days 04:53:36.000000000',format='%d days %H:%M:%S.000000000')
Time difference of NA secs
```

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12649641/calculating-time-difference-in-r. In short, you can't do date/time math with strings, as you're attempting here.

Comment: From `?strptime`, `%d` is "*Day of the month as decimal number (01–31).*", not a number of days. I don't have a solution, but this explains the behavior somewhat (more than 31 days results in `NA`)

Comment: @tluh It's not doing math, just coercing to a `difftime` object.

Comment: You might need to do a little parsing - extract the days as a string, convert to numeric, and add it to the result of using `as.difftime()` on the H:M:S part.

Comment: @Gregor That's good advice. I'll go down that route. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I also read into 'R' some time delta objects I had processed with 'Python' and had a similar issue with the `26 days 04:53:36.000000000` format. As Gregor said, %d in `strptime` is the day of the month as a zero padded decimal number so won't work with numbers >31 and there doesn't seem to be an option for cumulative days (probably because `strptime` is for date time objects and not time delta objects).

My solution was to convert the objects to strings and extract the numerical data  as Gregor suggested and I did this using the `gsub` function.

```
# convert to strings
data$tdelta <- as.character(data$tdelta)
# extract numerical data
days <- as.numeric(gsub('^.*([0-9]+) days.*$','\\1',data$tdelta))
hours <- as.numeric(gsub('^.*ys ([0-9]+):.*$','\\1',data$tdelta))
minutes <- as.numeric(gsub('^.*:([0-9]+):.*$','\\1',data$tdelta))
seconds <- as.numeric(gsub('^.*:([0-9]+)..*$','\\1',data$tdelta))
# add up numerical components to whatever units you want
time_diff_seconds <- seconds + minutes*60 + hours*60*60 + days*24*60*60
# add column to data frame
data$tdelta <- time_diff_seconds
```

That should allow you to do computations with the time differences. Hope that helps.

Comment: Thanks very much - I did something very similar