# Calculate number days between specific date and today's date in R

Tags: r

[image]

Hello,

i am trying to calculate the number of days since the complaint was registered. I wanted to calculate the number of days between "Date Notified" and today's date. i used the below command to get the result but it is showing me an error. Can anyone please help me !

```
Mergingopen%>%
  mutate(30 days since file opened = `Date Notified`,Sys.Date())
```

Comment: Probably a duplicate: https://stackoverflow.com/q/12649641/1531971

Comment: Possible duplicate of [calculating time difference in R](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12649641/calculating-time-difference-in-r)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try

```
Mergingopen %>%
        mutate('30 days since file opened' = as.numeric(difftime(Sys.Date(),
                                                                 `Date Notified`,
                                                                 units = c("days"))))
```